Hibernate Batch Insert - sorting of queries not working
I have a Spring Boot backend with Hibernate (on MySQL Database) running.
I was, according to several articels (like this one https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update) able to successfully enable Hibernates batch insert/update.
The main work was to switch to ID GenerationType Sequence (from Identity) and enable the spring boot properties ...
The log I get from the Proxy logger (see article above) shows that batching is enabled.
I also added
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.reWriteBatchedInserts=true

to spring boot application.properties to enable the sorting of queries per entity.
Unfortunately I get these kind of warnings:
WARN  o.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - The batch containing 3981315 statements could not be sorted. This might indicate a circular entity relationship.
Yes, roughly 4 millions of SQL-Queries!
This leads to very small batch sizes of 2 or 3 which drops the performance significantly.
My entity graph is consisting of two main entities only. The first one represents a tree node which has a releationship to itself to reflect the parent-child releationship on the tree.
The second one describes kind of a generic attribute these nodes can have. The main class here is an attribute, that, due to inheritance splits into several sub-entities.
I found relatively sparse information at all in hibernates documentation what this warning means.
Can anyone describe (or link to some information I was not able to find) how to setup tree structures and/or inheritance with id generation type sequence and batch inserts in a way that Hibernate can sort queries? Or is it better to directly go with JDBC Queries (or do something entirely different)?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Why so many statements in the first place. You should reduce (and specify) your batch sizes. Too large sizes will impact performance as well. You also mention MySQL which requires some additional settings for the JDBC driver as well (IIRC).

Batches of 100 to 1000 are optimal.

The amount of queries in the first place comes from the underlying object model that is not entirely under my control. Therefore the approach of batching queries. But that was not my question. My question was why hibernate is not able to sort!
In the meantime I think I found the reason: The object model is representing a tree like model where parent knows of it children but the child objects have knowledge about their parents. Therefore the (correct) warning.
I will (I think in September/Oktober) refactor the model and see whether the problem still exists... I'll keep this thread up to date
